# Android activity lifecycle

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle, onactivityresult, onrestoreinstancestate

What is called first when activity is restored? `onRestoreInstanceState` or `onActivityResult`?

Comment: Check [this answer related to activity life cycle](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8516056/265167), this may help you i guess!

Comment: The problem was solved few months ago!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From my experience, flow must be

```
onCreate
onStart
onRestoreInstanceState
onActivityResult
onResume
```

So, `onActivityResult` is called AFTER the `onRestoreInstanceState`.

[Here](http://androiddiscuss.com/1-android-discuss/65498.html) and [here](http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/lifecycleMethods.html) are sample code, which make clear about your doubt.